# How do I set <tabVisibilities> for Connections tab (SF2SF) in metadata?

Tags: metadata-api, permissions, profile, tab, mdapideploy

We have multiple orgs and I would like to deploy the setting to Hidden for all profiles other than SysAdmin for the Connections tab (Salesforce to Salesforce). I have tried by using these options, but they throw errors ('*no CustomTab named standard-Connections found*')

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>Connections</tab>
    <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

OR

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>standard-Connections</tab>
    <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

I can go into each org individually and set it to Hidden on the profiles, but with 36 orgs it becomes a bit of a pain. I was hoping to deploy it. Is it possible?